# .htaccess - Redirect old website to main domain but also some content to subdomain of the main domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdomain, http-status-code-301

I want to redirect an old domain (https & www) to the main one. I need to redirect it to the home page and blog. But, there are 4 pages on the old site I want to redirect to the subdomain of the main page.

How it should look:

> Oldwebsite1.com -> mainwebsite2.com

> Oldwebsite1.com/blog -> Mainwebsite2.com/blog

> Oldwebsite1.com/category1 -> new.mainwebsite2.com/category1

> Oldwebsite1.com/category2 -> new.mainwebsite2.com/category2 /// etc...

Will typical code like this work or do I need to adjust it?

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mainwebsite2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. These also handles optional `www` in your host name too.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##For Oldwebsite1.com -> mainwebsite2.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)Oldwebsite1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://mainwebsite2.com [R=301,L]

##For Oldwebsite1.com/blog -> Mainwebsite2.com/blog
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)Oldwebsite1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(blog)/?$ http://mainwebsite2.com/$1 [NC,R=301,L]

##For Oldwebsite1.com/category1 -> new.mainwebsite2.com/category1 OR Oldwebsite1.com/category2 -> new.mainwebsite2.com/category2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)Oldwebsite1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(category1|category2)/?$ http://new.mainwebsite2.com/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: I think OP wants `new.mainwebsite2.com` for `category1|category2`

Comment: @anubhava, Thank you sir I have changed it now, cheers.

Comment: Hello a thank you. I tried to use the code and it redirected well. But there is a problem. The blog redirected but blog posts are still on the old website. Is there a way to redirect them as well?

Comment: @Zuzka, could you please post sample url which is not working, let me know then.

Comment: Sure, I have blog with about 100 blog posts but only the blog category was redirected - without posts. So this is what doesnt work:  "Oldwebsite.com/specific-blog-post-about-business/ - > Mainwebsite.com/specific-blog-post-about-business/

Comment: @Zuzka, ok how about changing 8th line's rule to `RewriteRule (.*blog.*)/?$ http://mainwebsite2.com/$1 [NC,R=301,L]` once? Kindly do let me know how it goes. My current rule looks if uri starts from `block` but this rule will check if a uri contains `block` then perform redirection.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I changed it but blog posts are still on the old website. Everything else is working.

Comment: @Zuzka, how about changing 8th line with these 2 following Rules `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} blog [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://mainwebsite2.com/$1 [NC,R=301,L]` (these are 2 different lines showing single line in comments though)once and let me know. Please make sure you are changing your `^(?:www\.)Oldwebsite1\.com$ [NC]` on 7th line with your actual domain here too, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I changed the rules and nothing. It stopped redirecting "Oldwebsite1.com/blog" as well.

Comment: @Zuzka, ohh didn't think that should happen. Is string/word `blog` really existing inn your urls? Kindly confirm once, because its looking for blog string in uris.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I am using word `clanky` - but I always change word `blog` to `clanky` in the rules. The url exists as the main page for blog pages.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Sorry, I just noticed I used bad diacritics in `clanky` in the last rule. So I changed it. Blog category works fine but blog posts are still on the old website.

Comment: @Zuzka, could you please do let me know if you are using exactly same htaccess file which I shown or you have additional rules too? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 The one you recommended + These right under your rules: `RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`